# How can I make my bottom navigation bar to go all the way up when tapped like YouTube?

Tags: flutter

I've been making community flutter app, and currently working on bottom navigation bar.
As application support infinite list of posts, I need to implement simple way to scrolls all the way up to the top, and I want to use bottom navigation bar for that (when user touched post icon at bottom tab bar, it scrolls to the top like YouTube)

### This is what I need

I basically want to get a event and use it to control inner widgets.
For example, [sample gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYmX2.gif)

This is just explaining sample for what I want. If I touch Video Icon at bottom navigation bar, I want to switch button's text from "Next page" to "aaa" or something else.
As you can see, get an event and use it for other widgets is main issue for me now.
Use one of bottom tab's icon(post icon) to control many pages, such as inside the specific page's list or at main page for the same way is just what I'm looking for!

I won't use hard coding or static, Any advice would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: try to add some code or examples

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understood your requirement but I think this is basically what you need. Let me know if you need further clarification.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();

  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView(
          controller: _controller,
          children: List.generate(100, (int index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text('Item $index'),
            );
          }),
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Business',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'School',
          ),
        ],
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onTap,
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onTap(int i) {
    _controller.animateTo(
      0,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of it.

```
enum Status  {video , defaulf}
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

Status status = Status.defaulf;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {


return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
   

    actions: [
      IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.video_collection), 
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              status = Status.video;
            });
          }
      )
    ],
  ),
  body: Center(
    // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
    // in the middle of the parent.
    child: FlatButton(
      onPressed: (){
        print(status);
      },
      child: status == Status.defaulf
          ? Text("data")
          : Text("video"),
    )
  ),
  
);
}
}
```

You need a state indicates what to show as a text. You can change the button as well. Iconbutton at the app bar but I guess it is not a problem.